# Access child's __class__ from a parent's method in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

When I run the code below, I get a reference to the parent class `A` at the end, while I was hoping to refer to the child `B`.

```py
In [1]: class A:
    ...:     def f():
    ...:         print(__class__)
    ...: 

In [2]: class B(A): pass

In [3]: B.f()
<class '__main__.A'>
```

I know I can do something like

```py
In [4]: class A:
    ...:     def f(self):
    ...:         print(self.__class__)
    ...: 

In [5]: class B(A): pass

In [6]: B().f()
<class '__main__.B'>
```

but I'm wondering if there is any way I could drop the extra parentheses.

Comment: Why would you expect `B.f()` to do that?  It's just a function defined in A's class block.

Comment: @wim: Amusingly, it's not *just* a function; the fact that unqualified `__class__` works at all is because being defined within `A`'s `class` block changes `f` from what it would be if it weren't defined within `A`'s `class` block (it implicitly wraps it in a faked out closure scope that provides `__class__` as `A`). `__class__` is magic the OP doesn't understand; I suspect they thought it was run-time magic, when it's actually (kinda) definition-time magic (it's more class definition-time magic than function definition-time magic, but it's kinda both).

Comment: `type(B.f)` is function, `type(B().f)` is method.  The question title asks about "a parent's method" but the question body doesn't use a method.  A function with no arguments defined in a class block, and not decorated with @staticmethod, is a pretty strange thing to do in the first place so I'm sort of at a loss about what OP is trying to do here anyway.  XY question?

Comment: @wim: Sure, but folks new to Python (and even folks who aren't so new to it) often mix the terminology. Heck, in the Python 2 days, `B.f` was in fact a method (an unbound method, but subtly different from a plain function), so older reference materials would be justified in conflating them a bit in this particular case, especially since the term "method" can reasonably describe a function defined within a class in the abstract, even when it's not actually bound to a particular instance yet.

Comment: @wim: XY problem is entirely possible. I'm guessing they left off any arguments because they only wanted to use it in this instance-less scenario, and giving it any arguments would prevent them from even trying to call it. They probably didn't know about `@staticmethod` (if they did, they'd know about `@classmethod` and wouldn't need to ask the question).

Comment: Yup, I didn't know about the decorators or that `B.f` is actually a function, just assumed every function defined within a class would be called a method. Thanks for all the clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to call the function on the class as well, not just an instance, and know which class it was called on (and for an instance, the class of the instance it was called on), make the method a `classmethod`, e.g.:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        print(cls) 

class B(A):
    pass
```

[The `classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) makes [a descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor) that will automatically provide the class object it was called on, whether it was called on the class itself or an instance of the class, and provides the class object as the first argument, rather than an instance. It's almost exclusively used to define alternate constructors (for the purpose of taking some argument format not accepted by `__init__`, converting from that format to one `__init__` accepts, then ending with `return cls(converted args here)`), but if you're really insistent on:

1. Using classes for this, and
2. Not making instances of the classes for whatever reason

it can handle *both* your use cases (`B.f()` and `B().f()`); `classmethod` strips instance information when called, so the latter behaves identically to the former (they both pass `B` as the value of `cls` in `f`).

`print(__class__)` alone didn't work because `__class__` is *intentionally* tied to the class the function was defined in, as part of the machinery for making no-arg `super()` calls work (it uses some pretty awful hacks to make `super()` behave like it was really called with the first positional argument passed to the function, typically `self`, plus a `__class__` variable smuggled into a closure scope when the class the function was defined in finishes being defined); making `__class__` redefine itself based on being called on a subclass would turn all uses of `super()` into infinite recursion.